# How to Capture STDOUT from a Docker Container in GitHub Actions using 'docker://'?

Tags: docker, github, yaml, github-actions, stdout

I  have a custom GitHub Action where I use uses: docker://... to run a Docker container. The STDOUT and STDERR are automatically captured in the action's logs, but I need to capture the STDOUT separately for GitHub summary by running something like docker logs. However, since the container's lifecycle is managed by the GitHub runner, I don't have access to the container and docker info shows no docker running or stopped.

How can I capture the STDOUT from the Docker container in this scenario while keeping use: docker://?

Here's my GitHub Action configuration:

```
runs:
  using: composite
steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Run docker (student image)
      uses: docker://<image-from-registry>
      with:
        args: >
          version
```

I need a way to capture the STDOUT from the Docker container even though I can't access the container due to the GitHub runner managing its lifecycle.

I have tried using `steps.id.outputs.stdout`

Answer (score 1):

The `uses: docker://` directive is incredibly useful and horribly documented at the same time. The only workaround I have found is running something like:

```
- name: Run docker manually like a pleb
  id: docker_run
  run: >
    docker run --rm
    --workdir ${{ github.workspace }}
    --volume ${{ github.workspace }}:${{ github.workspace }}:rw
    -e "ENV_VAR" <image-from-registry> -e...
    version
    | printf "version=%s\n" "$(cat)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
- run: printf "Version is %s" "${{ steps.docker_run.outputs.version }}"
```